# Given a generating function for $\sum a_n z^n$, what is the generating function of $\sum a_n^2 z^n$

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, generating-functions

Given a generating function $G(z)$ for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$, what could be said about the generating function of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^2 z^n$, what algebraic form should it have?

For example, given the generating function for $G(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$, then the generating function for its cumulative sum, i.e. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k}^n a_k\right) z^n$ is $\frac{1}{1-z} G(z)$, which could be derived by the formulae for the convolution product of two generating functions
$$
 F(z) G(z) = \sum_n \left( \sum_{k=0}^n f_k g_{n-k} \right) z^n
$$
applied on the well know generating function of $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}.
$$
But I am looking for a formulae for the pointwise product to solve my problem?

Comment: There seems to be something off in your title.

Comment: sorry, my fault...

Comment: The "Hadamard product" of $\sum a_nz^n$ and $\sum b_nz^n$ is $\sum a_nb_nz^n$, so you are asking about the square of a power series (with respect to the Hadamard product). Searching for Hadamard product (and power series) may turn up something useful. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/formal-power-series-coefficient-multiplication

Answer (score 2):

This is the Hadamard product, in terms of generating functions:

$\begin{align*}
A(z)
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n \\
B(z)
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n \\
C(z)
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n b_n z^n
\end{align*}$

Sorry, but except for *very* special sequences there isn't any nice expression for $C(z)$ in terms of $A(z)$ and $B(z)$.